# Continuing math on my own?

Tags: soft-question

I am  in 6th grade and neither of my parents are mathematicians. I feel that at school though my teacher is great, the stuff I am studying (Pre Algebra) is just a little too elementary. I often find myself browsing math forums getting into trigonometry, linear algebra, quadratics equations, etc. But there is a lot of stuff that I sometimes need help with or need a more in depth explanation on. I don't know anyone who is a very math centered person and I therefore don't really have anyone to go to for these problems. My question is how can I efficiently further my mathematical education by myself?

Comment: You could try seeing if there is a math circle in your area that you could join. Also there might be summer math programs you could attend.  And you can always ask questions here.

Comment: @littleO Asking questions here is a very delicate issue (imo).  I frankly find it difficult to believe that math stack exchange would be an appropriate forum to ask general questions of this level.  I mean, general questions yes, but the OP is likely not to the stage where they are asking general questions appropriate for Math Stack Exchange.  I mean if you are looking for rejection, then math stack exchange is a good place to start...and I don't necessarily say that as a negative.  For the record, math stack is far more kind than the other forums it hosts.

Comment: @Jared I agree that there is a danger of being downvoted into oblivion if a question isn't phrased carefully, and that this might be discouraging.  That's a good point.  But I don't think there is any lower bound on the level of math questions that are considered to be on topic or appropriate for this site.  "[Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any level and professionals in related fields.](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: @Jared I partially agree with you. I My questions so far have been generally well received, although I do have to pick and choose what questions I can ask on here, because even though the Mathematics Stack Exchange is supposed to be for any level of math education, I think there is kind of an unspoken rule that puts a cut off on the level of math at about high school.

Answer (score 7):

You might enjoy The Art of Problem Solving.  Here is a link: 
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/

Answer (score 4):

While I've never used it myself, [Kahn Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org) is supposed to be very good for teaching yourself mathematics. It goes into some quite advanced topics as well so it should keep you covered for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Have you discussed this with your teachers and parents? If not, bring it up!

Depending on your school and location, you may try seeking:

- A school teacher who may volunteer to coach you. Ask the head of your school's math department for guidance.
- A school math club. These clubs often have a teacher sponsor and aim to expand your knowledge by training for math competitions. You can try to start one up, if such a club doesn't exist.
- A local tutoring center, if financially possible. I do this for work and have met quite a few students who are looking to advance their math.
- A local college that offers classes at your level. Ask the professor if you can sit in class for free. It's called unofficial auditing. He or she may be cool with it.

If these in-person ideas aren't what you're looking for, I second Loocid's suggestion about [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org). I've used their videos and exercises for students, and it's well put together.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You're in junior high, so reach out to the high school math teachers.  A junior or senior level math teacher (i.e. Algebra II, Pre-Calculus, and above) should be able to help with all of the topics you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some direction by writing software. It tends to check itself. For example, fractal programs or kinematics for game engines.